# Crystal Report Record Filtering 3 different ways per record CR10

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement, crystal-reports, records

I am using a command query in crystal reports to pull the information I need.
The query results look like so:

```
Amt      Date      Acc     Unit     Setup     Owner?     Owner
5.00  2016-03-01    1       A        A          Y          B
5.00  2016-03-01    2       A        B          N          null
5.00  2016-03-01    3       A        null       null       null
```

My flow of logic is: If the Owner? = "Y" then get the owner, else if the owner? = "N" or isnull, then get the setup, else if the setup is null, then get the unit.

In record selection I have tried an if-else-if statement to help filter each record, looking like this to just get the "B" units.:

```
If({Command.Owner? = "Y") Then {Command.Owner = "B")
Else if ({Command.owner? = "N" or isnull({Command.owner}) Then
     {Command.setup = "B")
Else if ({Command.owner? = "N" or isnull({Command.owner}) AND {command.setup} <> "B" Then
 {Command.unit} = "B"
```

Basically, what this is doing is checking if the Owner? is Y and then getting the records where the Owner is B, if that is N or null, then get the records where the setup is B, if both those are untrue then get the units that are B.

But it doesn't get every record. I want to be able to get all the records that are with this. Like

```
Amt      Date      Acc     Unit     Setup     Owner?     Owner
5.00  2016-03-01    1       A        A          Y          B
5.00  2016-03-01    2       A        B          N          null
5.00  2016-03-01    3       B        null       null       null
```

Would all be valid returns, but the record selection only grabs records that match the first criteria and then ignores the rest.

I have tried the same if-else-if with AND statements instead of Else, but that returns nothing. I have also done the same with OR, which returns nothing.

Is there a way to search every record, and if it matches one of those criteria then pull it and display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (edited for null sequencing)?

```
If (isnull({Command.owner}) or {Command.owner?} = "N") and not isnull({Command.setup} and {Command.Owner?} <> "Y") then {Command.setup} = "B"
Else if {Command.Owner?} = "Y" Then {Command.owner} = "B"
Else {Command.unit} = "B"
```

Comment: See I tried that, it only looks for the first if, then ignores the rest, I'm not sure why it doesn't continue the check

Comment: Try re-sequencing the logic to handle any and all nulls first?  [Record Selection and the Null Value Bug in Crystal Reports](http://www.isinc.com/2008/10/10/record-selection-and-the-null-value-bug-in-crystal-reports/)

Comment: Oh wow, amazing. I didn't think locations of isNull matters, I don't see how this hasn't been fixed yet, nonetheless this works, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Actually, judging from this, it seems that all IsNull() would have to come first, but what if the command.setup is null? simply throwing in isnull before the last else, would not return null setups